# isn't numeric in array element at perl

Tags: perl

im running script that handle list of files in same directory to do some of changes on these files  and then code working fine , but after i have added `use strict` and `use warnings` it returns an problem with :

> Argument "mobileOriginatedCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 72.
>
> Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use TAP3::Tap3edit;
use Data::Dumper;



printDir(".");
sub printDir{
opendir(DIR, $_[0]);
my @files;
my @dirs;
 (@files) = readdir(DIR);
 foreach my $file (@files) {
    if (-f $file and substr($file,0,2) eq "CD" ) {


     my $tap3 = TAP3::Tap3edit->new;

     my $tap_file = $file;
$tap3->decode($tap_file)  or  die $tap3->error; 

my $struct=$tap3->structure;
my $Tracker = $struct->{'transferBatch'};
if (defined $Tracker){

    my $rectag = $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'networkInfo'}->{'recEntityInfo'};

    map { $_->{'recEntityType'} = 4 if ( $_->{'recEntityType'} > 6) } @$rectag;

    my $calleventtag = $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'};

    my @indexes = reverse (grep { exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'supplServiceEvent'} } 0..$#$calleventtag);

    my $sup_event_cnt = $#indexes;

    foreach my $index (@indexes)
    {
    splice (@$calleventtag , $index,1);
    }

    my $total_events_cnt = $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'auditControlInfo'}->{'callEventDetailsCount'};
    $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'auditControlInfo'}->{'callEventDetailsCount'} = $total_events_cnt - $sup_event_cnt-1;

    if ( exists $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'batchControlInfo'}->{'operatorSpecInformation'} )
        {
            delete $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'batchControlInfo'}->{'operatorSpecInformation'};
        }
    if ( exists $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'auditControlInfo'}->{'operatorSpecInformation'} )
        {
            delete $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'auditControlInfo'}->{'operatorSpecInformation'};
        }

my $key;

# Will scan all the calls for MOC's and GPRS.
foreach $key ( @{$struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'} } ) {

    foreach ( keys %{$key} ) {

        if ( $_ eq "mobileOriginatedCall" )
        {

            if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'destinationNetwork'} )
            {
                delete $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'destinationNetwork'};
            }

            if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'} 
            && $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'} !~ m/^96279/ 
            )
            {
                delete $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'};
            }

            if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'camelServiceUsed'}  
            && $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'camelServiceUsed'}->{'camelServiceKey'} != 80
            )
            {
                delete $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'camelServiceUsed'};
            }

        }

        if ( $_ eq "gprsCall" )
        {

            if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'gprsCall'}->{'gprsBasicCallInformation'}->{'gprsDestination'}->{'accessPointNameOI'} )
            {
                delete $calleventtag->[$_]->{'gprsCall'}->{'gprsBasicCallInformation'}->{'gprsDestination'}->{'accessPointNameOI'};
            }

        }

    }
}


    $tap3->encode("$tap_file")  or  die $tap3->error; 
}    

    }

 } 

 closedir(DIR);
}
```

i think the problem with this part :

```
if ( $_ eq "mobileOriginatedCall" )
```

and

```
if ( $_ eq "gprsCall" )
```

each file of these file looks like this but with different number of calls :

trace stack :

```
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "mobileOriginatedCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 72.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Argument "gprsCall" isn't numeric in array element at ./5th_edit.pl line 96.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 60.
```

Comment: This would be much easier with line numbers.

Comment: @simbabque i have updated the warnnings with line numbers , can you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
if ( $_ eq "mobileOriginatedCall" ) {
   if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->...
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if ( $_ eq "mobileOriginatedCall" ) {
   if ( exists $calleventtag->["mobileOriginatedCall"]->...
```

Which means you are trying to get element number `mobileOriginatedCall` of the array referenced by `$calleventtag`, which makes no sense; `mobileOriginatedCall` isn't a number.

Comment: im running over loop on the list contains list of element so i just want to check if the element equal to  mobileOriginatedCall or gprsCall i just want to do the delete , sorry im still new can you show how can i fix it

Comment: I don't know what you data looks like, so I can't do so definitively, but my answer does take a guess

Comment: i have updated my question with the picture , each file of these files have a different number of calls but they look like this

Comment: I don't see `callEventDetails` anywhere in there. Please provide the *relevant portions* of the output of Data::Dumper (or similar)

Comment: it's on the left top of the picture

Comment: How could I miss that. But still, please provide the relevant portions of the output of Data::Dumper (or similar). Don't make the people you are helping force you to guess. (From what I see in the image, I would guess that `foreach ( keys %{$key} )` would fail, but that's not what you are getting.)

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; warn(Dumper($struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'}));`

Comment: thank you for your effort, still same error, i will ask a new question with idea about this loop maybe i can solve this, i believe in :)

Comment: Use that code to provide a dump of your data so we can see what it looks like. Provide a relevant portion of that dump.